# Save and reload position of drag and drop

Tags: jquery, dom, position

I have grid of 8 elements that are drag and droppable to any of the eight positions. I'm trying to save the positions of the dropped items so that when the page is reloaded the dragged items are in the same position the user placed them. I plan on storing these positions in a DB in the future but I have no idea where to start. Heres my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/AywmJ/170/
Any help is greatly appreciated!

I started with some simple position js but havent figured out how use the positions.

```
var testID = dragged.attr("id");
var pin = dragged;
var position = pin.position();
var pinLeft = position.left;
var pinTop = position.top;
alert("id: " + testID +"  left: " + pinLeft + ", top: " + pinTop );
```

Comment: You can save the positions as JSON in Cookie.

Comment: Would I have to save the position or each pin in a cookie? or is there an easy way to save all pins and their locations?